# Can't find Error in this syntax (If statement in forfiles batch)

Tags: batch

no matter what i try, i don't get the following line in a batch file on my win7 64-bit machine to work:

```
forfiles /P "I:\testroot" /C "CMD /C if /i @FILE==testung.txt del /s @FILE"
```

The code runs, no error is shown but the file testung.txt is not deleted.

If someone is interested in the official syntax from MS:

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

So where is the problem?

Comment: I:\testroot shouldn't be in quotes, according to the TN article

Comment: doesn't matter, i already tried..

Comment: Where can I find more information on '@FILE', my googlefu isn't working

Comment: under the link above in the article there is way down a section where they explain all the @Variables (are those really variables? the kinda look it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a couple of double-quotes...

What's going on is that `@FILE` returns the file name wrapped in double-quotes, so you need to reference it as such in your IF-statement comparison.

You can witness this by doing a `forfiles /P "I:\testroot" /C "CMD /C echo @FILE"`, and seeing that `testung.txt` is echoed as `"testing.txt"`.

To use double-quotes within a string (instead of as a string delimiter) you need to escape them with a `\`.

So once we do that, it should work:

`forfiles /P "I:\testroot" /C "CMD /C if /i @FILE==\"testung.txt\" del /s @FILE"`